# Elegant way for Oracle SQL/HiveQL to get mode value from each group?

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

This is pandas example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'k':'a a a b b c c d e f'.split(' '),'v':[1,2,3,1,0,np.nan,2,4,np.nan,1 ]})
df.groupby('k').apply(lambda df: np.mean(pd.Series.mode(df.v))).reset_index()
```

Data example like this:

```
   k    v
0  a  1.0
1  a  2.0
2  a  3.0
3  b  1.0
4  b  0.0
5  c  NaN
6  c  2.0
7  d  4.0
8  e  NaN
9  f  1.0
```

Output:

```
   k    0
0  a  2.0
1  b  0.5
2  c  2.0
3  d  4.0
4  e  NaN
5  f  1.0
```

How to get mode value for each group using SQL/HQL?

Comment: Your results are not the mode.  The best I can figure is that they are the continuous median or perhaps just the average.  Please clarify.  Do you actually know what "mode" means?  Your sample data has no good examples that represent the mode.

Comment: When got several max counts, using the average of them.

Comment: . . As far as I know, the average of modes is meaningless.  You can consider a bi-modal distribution, where the average might have no values at all.  Averages make sense for medians because medians are "next to each other".

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in oracle SQL?

```
SELECT k, STATS_MODE(v) FROM mytable GROUP BY k;
```

for hive there is no official mode function. However you can use this -

```
select k,v from (
    select k,v, count(v) as v_cnt
    from mytable
    group by k,v
    order by v_cnt desc
    limit 1
) t1
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks. There is a little bug in my mind yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
with count_table as (select k,v,count(v) as v_cnt from mytable group by k,v),
rk_table as (select k,v,row_number() over(partition by k order by v_cnt desc) rk from count_table)
select k,v from rk_table where rk=1
```